# Instance creation in Openstack Nova - Logfile

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

I need to keep track of Instance creation in openstack Nova.

That is I need to perform some special operations on creation of new instance in openstack.

So that I need to know where all the details are getting stored (In Log file).

Please some one guide me regarding the Log file for tracking instance creation or some other way to track the same.

Answer (score 0):

As I am aware you have to look in the following services' log files

- `nova-scheduler` (oftenly installed on controller node). This will show which 'server' will host the newly created Virtual Machine.
- The logs of `nova-compute` service running on the host that the Virtual Machine was instantiated.
- You can additionally check the logs of `qemu` and `libvirt` (again on the host that the Virtual Machine was instantiated)

Have in mind that the info you will find there, depends on the 'logging level' you have set in each service configuration files. For more information about how you can configure the OpenStack Components logging refer to the official documentation "[Logging and Monitoring](http://docs.openstack.org/openstack-ops/content/logging_monitoring.html)".

Comment: Could you please let me know the conf file structure for the same

Comment: For my case, the default configuration is sufficient enough for the troubleshooting information I need. I edit my answer adding the link for the official "Logging and Monitoring" documentation. I do not think I can provide you with more info than the one included in the quide.